# import a python dictionary variable, failed: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute

Tags: python, robotframework

import a python dictionary variable, failed: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute
For example:

`Variable.robot`

```
Data = {'Url':'https:',
         'Username':'aaa',
         'Password':'bbb'}
```

and in `test.robot`

```
log  ${Data.Url}
```

Error meaasge

```
Resolving variable '${Data}'failed: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Url'
```

Comment: That is not the way to access dictionaries. Try `Data['Url']` instead.